# If $x^Tx \geq y^Ty$ under what conditions for $Q$ is $x^TQx \geq y^TQy$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

I am working on an optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
 \min_{v_1,\dots,v_n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} v_i^T Q v_i,
\end{equation}
where the dynamics is $v_{i+1} = A_iv_i$ and $Q \succeq 0$. $A_i$ is a function of $v_i$, i.e, $A_i = f(v_i)$. And based on $A_i$, the optimization would not be quadratic.

Assume $\exists ~ A$ such that $||A||_2 \succeq ||A_i||_2 ~\forall i$ (specifically $I \succeq A^2 \succeq A_i^2 \succeq 0$, and $A_i$ and $A$ are symmetric). I am trying to see if I can bound the cost $v_i^TQv_i$ using $A$ and solve a sub-optimal convex problem. I am wondering if
\begin{equation}\label{eq:cntrl}
 AQA \geq A_iQA_i ~\forall ~ i.
\end{equation}
Since $A^2 \succeq A_i^2$, for some vector $u$, I define $x = Au, y = A_iu$, so that $x^Tx \geq y^Ty$.

If the vector dot product $x^Tx \geq y^Ty$ and $Q$ is a symmetric PSD matrix ($ Q \succeq 0$), is $x^TQx \geq y^TQy$? If no, what other conditions must $Q$ satisfy for $x^TQx \geq y^TQy$ to hold? How about if $x^Tx > y^Ty$?

Alternatively, is there a path to directly show $AQA \geq A_iQA_i$? If not, what about when $A^2\succ A_i^2$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This site is not a "give me the answer."  We need more information from you. Your thoughts, the source of the question, what motivated the question, definitions and theorems you think might apply, or some effort.

Comment: @Uduak Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to address the following. Where did you come across this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, I have elucidated.

Answer (score 5):

This is true only if $Q$ is a constant multiple of the identity.  If not, it has two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$.  Let $x,y$ be unit eigenvectors corresponding to these respective eigenvalues and you see that $x^T x = y^T y = 1$ while $x^T Q x = \lambda_1 < \lambda_2 = y^T Q y$.

Comment: Thank you @Nate. What about if $x^Tx > y^Ty$?

Comment: @Uduak: It doesn't help, just rescale $x$ so that it is an eigenvector with norm $1+\epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ very small.  Then $x^T Q x = (1+\epsilon) \lambda_1$ which will still be less than $\lambda_2$ when you take $\epsilon$ small enough.  The value of $x^T Q x$ depends deeply on not only the magnitude of $x$ (which is all that $x^T x$ gives you), but also its direction, so it is fundamentally impossible to have a relationship anything like what you are looking for.